# How to write a stored procedure in mysql to delete records from entire tables in database using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables joined together in MySQL and now i need to write a stored procedures to delete a record from all tables by passing ID  and database name from procedure parameters dynamically. while i call my procedures it's like the below code:

```
CALL delete_case_fromTables('databasename',1);
```

I wrote a procedure as below, but its not what i need, but i need to delete a record from all 4 tables in a database dynamically.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_cms_case_demo(IN DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(200),IN CASE_URN INT)

BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', DATABASE_NAME,'.appellateinv WHERE case_urn= ', CASE_URN);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
```

Please  Help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: what did you done for this so far?

Comment: i revised my code, please take a look

Comment: How is it not doing what you want?

Comment: Do you have cascade delete on the 'joined' tables? Can you publish the table definitions?

Comment: P.Salmon, first thanks for your prompt reply. actually no the joint tables did not apply on cascade delete. Therefore,i need to delete all records from tables in database which are joint based on key ( unique ID) logically. is it possible to delete records from tables with out knowing even the table name from schema? I may use cursor  for looping the tables for deletion of record dynamically. that is what i want but can not do it.

Comment: Do all the 'joined' tables have the same id field (case_urn)?

Comment: YES tables have the same id field (case_urn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news (possibly) procedure is fine.

```
    drop table if exists cascade2,cascade3;
    drop table if exists cascade1;

    create table cascade1 (case_urn int primary key, msg varchar(10));
    create table cascade2 (case_urn int , msg varchar(10));
    create table cascade3 (case_urn int , msg varchar(10));

    alter table cascade2
        add foreign key fk2(case_urn) references cascade1(case_urn) on delete cascade;
    alter table cascade3
        add foreign key fk3(case_urn) references cascade1(case_urn) on delete cascade;

    insert into cascade1 values (1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');  
    insert into cascade2 values (1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');  
    insert into cascade3 values (2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');    


    call p_delete_cascade('sandbox',1);
    select 'c1', case_urn , msg from cascade1
    union all
    select 'c2', case_urn , msg from cascade2
    union all
    select 'c3', case_urn , msg from cascade3   

procedure
drop procedure if exists p_delete_cascade;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_delete_cascade(IN DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(200),IN CASE_URN INT)

BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', database_name,'.cascade1 WHERE case_urn = ', Case_urn);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$

delimiter ;
```

Result

```
+----+----------+------+
| c1 | case_urn | msg  |
+----+----------+------+
| c1 |        2 | bbb  |
| c1 |        3 | ccc  |
| c2 |        2 | bbb  |
| c2 |        3 | ccc  |
| c3 |        2 | bbb  |
| c3 |        3 | ccc  |
+----+----------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To delete on a shared column name

```
drop procedure if exists p_delete_on_shared_col_name;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_delete_on_shared_col_name(IN DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(200),IN CASE_URN INT)

BEGIN

     declare tablenames varchar(1000);
     declare tname varchar(100);

     select group_concat(table_name) 
     into tablenames
     from information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
     where column_name = 'case_urn'
      ;

      #insert into debug_table(msg) values (tablenames);

     while instr(tablenames,',') > 0 do
        set tname = substring(tablenames,1,instr(tablenames,',') -1);
        set tablenames = replace(tablenames,concat(tname,','),'');
        SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', database_name,'.',tname ,' WHERE case_urn = ', Case_urn);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        #insert into debug_table(msg) values (@sql);
     end while ;
     set tname = tablenames;
     SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', database_name,'.',tname ,' WHERE case_urn = ', Case_urn);
     #insert into debug_table(msg) values (@sql);

     PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I need Something like `DELETE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'  AND CASE_URN=123`  it should delete record 123 from all tables joint together in a database. can i do it in stored procedures?

Comment: You are thinking on the right lines but you should be looking at information_schema.columns and you should not attempt to delete information_schema.columns but instead write code to delete from the tables found in information_schema.columns something like code added to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, i will try that and let you know if its working.